# Rails route to first record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I've got the following link:

```
<%= link_to 'About', url_for(Page.first) %>
```

I'd would prefer to have a named route, something like this instead:

```
<%= link_to 'About', first_page_path %>
```

I know I can create a helper method to achieve this, but I was wondering if there is a 'Rails way' for doing this?

Comment: does Page.first change much? Can you load it during initialization phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a very railsy thing to do so it's hard to advise on the railsy way to do it.  However, the logic for the 'About' page just happening to be the first page in your database table is quite brittle and should be locked away in a model somewhere, since the models hold logic.  I would do something like this

```
#route
get '/about', to: 'page#about'
```

which will go to the Page controller's "about" action, which is the most appropriate way to deal with this.

Then in the page controller i would have

```
def about
  @page = Page.about_page
  #render the Page show action or whatever
end
```

and this in turn uses this Page class method

```
#in Page model
#class methods
class << self
  def about_page
    self.first
  end
end
```

This way, if you decide at some point to use a less brittle way of picking which page to use for About, then it's a change to the model method, and the url, controller etc stay the same.

Now, in your view, you can link to it like

```
<%= link_to 'About', "/about" %>
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this technique, it means my user can edit their about page :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going into the details of the 'why would you want such a thing'. I don't think that you can you what you want. The routes are loaded when the app goes up, so what would be the behaviour if the current first record gets deleted?.

What I would recommend is having the helper method you spoke about but with a little twist

```
def first_or_record(page_id = nil)
   Page.find_by(id: page_id) || Page.first
end
```